# How to unit test an Action method that takes Array of an Object and returns JsonResult in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, jsonresult

I am trying to write a unit test in `Visual C# Unit Test` project.

I pass an empty `Array` of **Frame** class and that returns a `JSON` object.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SubmitBowlingScore(Frame[] frames)
    {
        int totalScore= 0;
        var objScore = new EngineService();

        for (int i = 0; i < frames.Length; i++)
        {
            Boolean wasSpare = false;

            if (i > 0 && objScore.IsSpare(frames[i-1]))
            {
                wasSpare = true;
            }
            totalScore += objScore.CalculateScore(frames[i], wasSpare);
        }

        return Json("{\"score\":"+ totalScore + "}");
    }
```

Hoping to test with the following entry: **But no idea how!!!**

```
 [{""1stRoll"":2,""2ndRoll"":2 ,""3rdRoll"":0},
  {""1stRoll"":4,""2ndRoll"":8 ,""3rdRoll"":0},
  {""1stRoll"":6,""2ndRoll"":2 ,""3rdRoll"":0}];
```

Any help/idea/suggestion would be appreciated for the following unit test. How **SubmitBowlingScore()** would take the **Frame []** data as a parameter?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SubmitBowlingScore()
    {
        //Arrange
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        //Act
        JsonResult result = controller.SubmitBowlingScore(**What goes here???**) as JsonResult;

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(JsonResult, "No JsonResult returned from action method.");
        Assert.AreEqual(@"{[{""1stRoll"":""2"",""2ndRoll"":2 ,""3rdRoll"":0},{""1stRoll"":""2"",""2ndRoll"":8 ,""3rdRoll"":0},{""1stRoll"":""6"",""2ndRoll"":2 ,""3rdRoll"":0}],""Count"":3,""Success"":true}",
               result.Data.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: To start , Don't do string concatenations to return your json structure. You can return an anonymous object like `return Json(new { score = 250 });`

Comment: Ok I understand that for the Action method itself in the controller. But for the unit test method?

Comment: One more thing I could see is, you are directly newing up EngineService().  Are you aware of Dependency Injection? EngineService is a dependency on the controller, and so it should be rather injected instead of using new keyword and creating an object yourself. That way you have loose coupling, and that loose coupling enables not only unit testing, but also makes the system extensible. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing your business logic with your presentation logic. You should move the entire body of your controller method to an object that calculates the score based on the frames. Once you've got that, there's nothing to test in the controller (unless you don't trust the MVC framework..)

My rendition of your *Frame* model:

```
public class Frame
{
    public int FirstRoll { get; set; }
    public int SecondRoll { get; set; }
    public int ThirdRoll { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the business logic as an extension.  You might want to break this out into its own class or possibly make it a member of your *EngineService* class.

```
public static class FrameExtensions
{
    public static int SumFrameScores(this Frame[] frames)
    {
        //break out early if no frames have been recorded
        if (frames.Length == 0) return 0;

        int totalScore = 0;
        var objScore = new EngineService();

        for (int i = 0; i < frames.Length; i++)
        {
            bool wasSpare = objScore.IsSpare(frames[i - 1]);
            totalScore += objScore.CalculateScore(frames[i], wasSpare);
        }

        return totalScore;
    }
}
```

When you're testing, you can test directly against your C# classes / types so you don't need to be worried about JSON/presentation layer data translation.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SubmitBowlingScore()
{
    //Arrange
    var frames = new Frame[]
    {
            new Frame {FirstRoll = 2, SecondRoll = 2, ThirdRoll = 0},
            new Frame {FirstRoll = 2, SecondRoll = 6, ThirdRoll = 0},
            new Frame {FirstRoll = 0, SecondRoll = 9, ThirdRoll = 0}
    };
    //Act
    var score = frames.SumFrameScores();

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(21, score);
}
```

Finally, your controller is reduced to the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitBowlingScore(Frame[] frames)
{
    var finalScore = frames.SumFrameScores();
    return Json(new { score = finalScore });
}
```